# Running ionic app on emulator renders no fonts or content

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I am having this weird problem with my Ionic app. If I run it on device it works ok but if I try to run it on an emulator it does not render the contents besides the background of the menu.

I can "interact" with the content if I know where to click.

I have tested with Microsoft Android Emulator and Genymotion.

I also have tested the conference example App (from Ionic) and it also renders in this way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not related to Ionic or the emulator but to my video card driver. The latest driver update fix it.